# Usage of base() in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I've been learning C# and wanted to review some open source projects to see some good written code. I found a project called Todomoo on sourceforge and there's a part that is puzzling me:

```
public class Category {

    // Note properties
    private int id = 0;
    private string name = "";
    private Color colour = Color.Gray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new category.
    /// </summary>
    public Category() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load a category from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id">ID of the category</param>
    public Category(int id) : base() {
        Load(id);
    }
```

Here it uses `base()` in one of the constructors, but the class is not a derived class. So what exactly is that for?

And why is the syntax of `base()` is that way and not like:

```
    public Category(int id) {
        base();
        Load(id);
    }
```

Comment: It would be the default constructor on an object class.  Where did you get this code, the use of `base()` is useless in a case like this, I wouldn't use the source of this code in the future.

Comment: In C# the root class is `System.Object`, so it is indeed a derived class.

Comment: +1 @Ramhound, there's a few other things which are wrong with this class (the fact it loads itself from the database being one of them)

Comment: @hattenn: My guess is that it was a typo, and instead maybe should be this() instead of base().  Google "Constructor Chaining" for more info.

Comment: @WonkotheSane The same thing is used in more than one place, I doubt it was a typo.

Comment: @hattenn: fair enough.  Perhaps it was a misunderstanding of base() vs. this() then?  The only reason I push this a little bit is that the default constructor is not calling base().  Or, perhaps its just an overall questionable design... :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> but the class is not a derived class

The class is a derived class - it implicitly inherits from `System.Object`. It is not clear why anyone would invoke `base()` constructor for `System.Object`, though: it is done implicitly as well.

As far as the syntax goes, my guess is that C# adopted a syntax that is close to C++ initializer lists, not to Java invocation of base constructors.

Answer (score 14):

Every class in C# is a derived class from **System.Object**
[Reference of Object in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first question, all user-defined classes inherit from at least one other class (Object). That means that defining a default constructor as the parent constructor is nearly always valid (it isn't only when the object inherits more directly from something else which does not have a visible default constructor). However, in this case, it's redundant; the default constructor for the base class will be invoked if it exists and is accessible from the child, without you having to say so.

Second, unlike method overrides, choosing whether and where to extend the functionality of a base class constructor isn't an option. A constructor for the base class *must* be called to initialize data members in the parent (which you may or may not have access to in the child), and this *must* happen before invoking the child constructor (in case the child requires any parent structure to exist). So, instead of allowing you to call a base class constructor wherever you want to, they force you to define the one you want to have invoked when this particular child constructor is used, and the runtime will handle the when and where.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call the constructor somewhere in your constructor code, because the language restricts this. In terms of the intermediate language, a constructor is just another method call.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, all classes derived from `System.Object`.

In your specific example, `base()` calls the default constructor of `System.Object`. This actually makes no real sense, as the default constructor of the base class is always called, even if `base()` is not specified.

For example, the following code

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public Foo2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo2");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo2 d = new Foo2();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

prints

> Foo
>
> Foo2

Answer (score 1):

its a extern constructor that constructs this before the Category constructor go play with it when you do `base();` there will nothing happen because its a constructor and returns something and `this = new base()` will result in a error